# Single Child taxonomy and its template file (single-{}.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Simple question probably. But I have looked everywhere and I couldn't find it.

First I have a custom post type called "world". In there I have a Taxonomy called "location" and a country "England" as parent. The child of this taxonomy is "London".

My question is: what is the single.php file for this construction? I have tried:

- single-location.php
- single-england.php
- single-location-england.php
- single-england-london.php

But nothing works. It gives me a 404. Anyone know's whats going on?

As requested by Amit:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_world' );
function cptui_register_my_cpts_world() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'world', '' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'world', '' ),
        );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'world', '' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "world", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "menu_position" => 20,"menu_icon" => "dashicons-palmtree",      
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),      
        "taxonomies" => array( "location" ),        
    );
    register_post_type( "world", $args );

// End of cptui_register_my_cpts_world()
}
```

Comment: Please share your custom post type code

Comment: Your single page for CPT `world` is `single-world.php`. Read about [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). For taxonomies you should use `taxonomy-{taxonomy_name}.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `single-world.php` for CPT. and also don't forgot to reset your permalinks settings.